# How to show "how many" items are in stock currently on product page? [Magento2]

Tags: magento2, stock

Currently it only shows "in stock" or "not in stock".

Can I somehow show how many items are in stock if there are any products in stock?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Very easy way is use magento default function called "Only X left Threshold".

Answer (score 0):

Make ajax query to [Stock Status API](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1GetStockStatusBySkuGet) and show quantity on product page